# How to use ECMAScript 6 node.js v4.2.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, ecmascript-6

When I try using `let` it returns this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let i = 0;
                                                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

I heard v4 had ECMAScript 6 support with no need for babel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be in strict mode (see your error message) to use ES6 features:

```
"use strict";
let yourcode = "here";
```

EDIT: Thanks @user5448026, I totally messed it up here.

Comment: `"use strict";` worked `"strict mode";` did not.